# zsh doesn't work in the vscode built-in terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code

`echo $SHELL`

logged: `/bin/zsh`

why the built-in shell is still `bash`

what should I config `vscode` the to make the zsh works in the built-in terminal?

Comment: have you had the time to verify that my answer works? If so, please mark it as correct!

Answer (score 3):

@Ale's answer is no longer valid! It should be used the following instead:

```
"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.osx": "zsh"
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work on the latest Visual Studio Code 1.75.1. Setting this option leads to `The terminal process failed to launch: A native exception occurred during launch (exec() failed: Bad CPU type in executable).`

The CPU is M2 Max

Answer (score 2):

**For those who are using MAC**

1. Launch Visual Studio Code and go to Settings.
2. In Settings, click on the features dropdown and then on Terminal
3. Click on edit in settings.json (the icon at the top right) and add this line of code to the user settings json file:

> "terminal.integrated.shell.osx": "/bin/zsh"

4. then you must close that terminal with the trash icon.

that's it, now if you open another terminal you should see the ZSH terminal.

Comment: While this config is deprecated, Step 4 (trashing the current terminal and launching a new one) was the answer to why bash kept reappearing for me after app restarts.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `terminal.integrated.shell.linux` property as described [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal#_configuration). If you need to pass arguments to zsh, use the `terminal.integrated.shellArgs.linux` property.

Comment: This is assuming you're using linux. If you're using MacOS or Windows, use `terminal.integrated.shell.osx` or `terminal.integrated.shell.windows` correspondingly.

Answer (score 0):

@ccoutinho updated Ale DC's answer to the proper path:

> "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.osx": "zsh"

But I also needed Ale DC's extra tip to trash the currently displayed embedded terminal (clicking the trash icon at the top right of the terminal tab). Otherwise I had one instance showing zsh and another refused to show zsh and it was driving me crazy.

Hope that helps.